# Cgridview Ajax Won't Sort Grid

Tags: yii

I think it happened when I upgraded to yii 1.1.14. Now it can't sort nor search columns in CGridView.
I have no idea why is it. I tried to remove every .js file I added manually but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] There were 2 problem

1. I used my css to customize CDetailView and I didn't put correct path to loading.gf, up,gif and down.gif. I fixed that and it was better
2. In my models, function search(), I used "condition" and "order" as my sql query and that was the thing that stopped CDetailGrid to be functional. I've changed everything to compare() and it worked